# English or Telugu translation of Narasimha Purana

Tags: translation-request, resource, book-recommendation, upapuranas

Could anyone tell me which is the best translation of Narasimha Purana in English or Telugu?

I'm looking for a physical book.

Comment: Hello. We provide translations of texts. It is subjective whether it is best or not. Visit [ask] and take a [tour] of our site.

Comment: Thanks, what I meant was widely accepted translation or rather authoritative one.

Comment: you need to edit your question. asking for 'best' is subject to opinion. your question as it stands may be closed.

Comment: Note that shopping recommendation is off-topic.

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/NarasimhaPuranaWithEnglishTranslation/Narasimha%20Purana%20with%20English%20Translation#page/n0/mode/1up might be helpful..it contains Sanskrit verses with English translation...

Comment: @soulking that book is not available as Physical book in India. But that's the best translation in English available right now.

Comment: Thanks I downloaded the pdf and yes there is no author but I gambled and ordered a version which mostly likely be the same on the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Narasimha Purana with English translation and Sanskrit verses in pdf version can be found in [archive](https://archive.org/stream/NarasimhaPuranaWithEnglishTranslation/Narasimha%20Purana%20with%20English%20Translation#page/n0/mode/1up).

I could see many [sources](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=narasimha+purana) from where you can order this in a physical book form, now which one is best comes under shopping recommendation and is off topic here.

Comment: Thanks I downloaded the pdf and yes there is no author but I gambled and ordered a version which mostly likely be the same on the pdf.

Comment: That archive.org link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is dated, and not sure if my response will help. Any case for others who may stumble upon this question -

Yes an English translation is available published by Parimal Publication here:

http://www.parimalpublication.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=4&product_id=78

But please note that I cannot suggest if it is the **best** translation. Like other responders noted, that classification is subjective.

In general, translators have their own omissions and commissions, and interpretations vary.